# Creating an initializer list in C

Tags: c

How do you create an initializer list in C?  Do you have to use a struct or union?

Because currently I have written code that apparently has a problem with how many initialized variables I have.

Compiling error:
**Number of initializers cannot be greater than the number**

Comment: can you please share your code

Comment: Please update your question with a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow/help/mcve) of the problem.  Otherwise, we have no way of knowing exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct S
{
    int a, d, p;
};

#define S_INITIALIZER { 12, 10, 77 }

struct S s = S_INITIALIZER;
```

You (typically) provide a value for each member. If you provide less, the remaining members are zero-initialized (C99, 6.7.8.21). If you provide more, you will get a compiler warning and the additional initializer values are discarded.

Edit: As Olaf pointed out (thanks!), it is better to use designated initializers:

```
#define S_INITIALIZER { .a = 12, .d = 10, .p = 77 }
```

This way, the initializer is robust against changes of the struct associated with:

```
struct S
{
    int d, a, o, p;
    //        ^ new value; a and d inverted!
};
```

is still initialized as before, o is initialized to 0 (C99 6.7.8.19). And if you now drop `p`, you get a compile error – at least with gcc.

Actually, the standard states:

> If a designator has the form
>      . identifier
>   then the current object (defined below) shall have structure or union type and the
>   identifier shall be the name of a member of that type.

(C99 6.7.8.7). However, did not find what happens if not doing so.

Similarly:

> No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity being initialized.

(C99 6.7.8.2), again no word if doing otherwise (providing more elements). Discarding additional elements seems to be legal, not compiling does not seem to be illegal either...

Comment: That a very nice C answer :)  (Good spot, cheers)

Comment: `If you provide more, the code won't compile`...can you quote something?

Comment: [it compiles](http://ideone.com/6cHXUV), though I agree, that warning should not be ignoned, `will not compile` is an overstatement here.

Comment: Bad practice. Why There is no need for a macro. And this is very error-prone if the `struct` changes, it might pass by unnoticed. If**f** you use such a macro, designated initialisers are a must.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, updated the answer appropriately.

Comment: @Aconcagua short question: in your second code `#define S_INITIALIZER { .a = 12, .b = 10, .p = 77 }` should the `.b` not be `.d`?

Comment: @KevinWallis Of course it should - obviously, have been inattendent... thanks for the hint.